# How to Get html table td value while clicking the Linkbutton and get the value in cs code through the button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, html-table, asplinkbutton

[Please Click Here for Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64m4H.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your .cs code? (Just to get idea how you are handling the click event.)

From the code what I can think of the possible solution is (in code behind file):

```
    void lnkBtn_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
             string s = "You clicked: " + e.CommandArgument;
    }
```

Comment: thanks kirtan for your reply.... here is my .cs code behind

`protected void lnkBtn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string btnNumber = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            lblTitleid.Text = btnNumber;
            this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            Data_Retrieve();
        }`

Comment: I get no data, i mean null (" ") value. bro i want to pass table td value in .cs code behind but i get "" (null) value.

Comment: Ok.. Then can you try this: `commandargument="<%# Eval("BOOKID" )%>"`

Comment: bro i already try this: `commandargument="<%# Eval("BOOKID" )%>"` but it shows same result (null).

Comment: In such a case I can think of two options. 
1. Add onClick event handler `OnClick="lnkBtn_Command"` and read the argument. 

2. Add `CommandName="<%# Eval("BOOKID") %>"`.